# How to use cursors, triggers and stored procedures for calculating prices in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am working on computerising a business and I am asked to put all the company's information in a database.

I have to calculate the prices for booking of trucks, which the equation is as follows

```
price = (cost of a litre of fuel * litres of fuel needed) + (hours of rent x 500) x number of trucks
```

Where: **cost of a litre of fuel = price/L**

and: **Litres of fuel needed = 1/ (number of kilometres per litre) * kilometres of journey**

I have already populated my tables and the tables I will work with look like this

Below are my tables truck, contract and payment:

```
    CREATE TABLE Truck
    (  Plate_No   VARCHAR   PRIMARY KEY,
       Model      VARCHAR  NOT NULL,
       Make       VARCHAR  NOT NULL,
       Year       CHAR(4)       NOT NULL,
       Mileage    VARCHAR  NOT NULL,
       LoadWeight CHAR(5)      NOT NULL,
       Fitness    bit                ,
       DriverID    CHAR(15)     REFERENCES Driver(DriverID),
       price_per_L    CHAR(10)      NOT NULL,
       km_per_L       CHAR(10)      NOT NULL );

     Insert into Truck values ('1082 ZM 98','CF.85410', 'DAF', '1998', '30000', '2550', '1', 'D109', '49.50','3.5');
     Insert into Truck values ('1385 CZ 99','CF.85410', 'DAF', '1999', '14670', '3000', '1', 'D101', '49.50','4');
     Insert into Truck values ('1633 NJ 97','CF.85410', 'DAF', '1997', '25698', '1500', '0', 'D032', '49.50','4.9');
     Insert into Truck values ('1763 ZR 98','CF.85410', 'DAF', '1998', '34564', '1660', '1', 'D345', '49.50','6');



    CREATE TABLE Contract 
     (  ContractID   CHAR(15)     PRIMARY KEY,
        Plate_No     VARCHAR      REFERENCES Truck(Plate_No),
        ClientID     CHAR(15)     REFERENCES Client(ClientID),
        TimeIn       TIME         NOT NULL,
        TimeOut      TIME         NOT NULL,
        DateIn       DATE         NOT NULL,
        DateOut      DATE         NOT NULL,
        No_of_trucks INT          CHECK (No_of_trucks<5),
        litres_of_fuel_needed    CHAR(5)     NOT NULL,
        km_of_journey            char(5)     NOT NULL,
        location                 VARCHAR NOT NULL);

  INSERT INTO Contract VALUES ('C0001', '1082 ZM 98', '102', '10:00', '16:00','18-01-2019', '18-01-2019', '1', ' ', '47.5', 'Savannah Sugar Factory Omnicane');
  INSERT INTO Contract VALUES ('C0002', '1763 ZR 98', '103', '13:00', '20:00','15-01-2019', '15-01-2019', '1', ' ', '18.7', 'CMT, Vacoas-Phoenix');
  INSERT INTO Contract VALUES ('C0004', '1385 CZ 99', '104', '08:00', '13:00', '11-01-2019', '11-01-2019', '1', ' ', '57.6', 'SSR International Airport');
  INSERT INTO Contract VALUES ('C0003', '1763 ZR 98', '105', '21:00', '07:00', '21-01-2019', '22-01-2019', '1', ' ', '25.2', 'Cascavelle Shopping Village');


    CREATE TABLE Payment_info
       (  ClientID   CHAR(15)  NOT NULL,
          ContractID CHAR(15)  NOT NULL,
          Price      CHAR(10)  NOT NULL,
          Payment_method  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (ClientID, ContractID));

Insert into Payment_info values ('102','C0001','','Cheque');
Insert into Payment_info values ('103','C0002','','Cash');
Insert into Payment_info values ('104','C0004','','Card');
Insert into Payment_info values ('105','C0003','','Cash');
```

The Price will go into table Payment_info.
Litres of fuel needed goes into table Contract

I will have to use triggers, stored procedures and cursors to make this. 
I'll be glad if someone could help.

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to ask question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't use images, or even worse, pictures of images. It is much better if you provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you need :

I assumed that for each booking there is a distinct ContractID and the period of booking is 24hours. Otherwise, the DATEDIFF below is not sufficient.

You can put this query in a stored procedure like below:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE Price_Booking_Trucks AS //query inside..
```

Or simply run the query :

```
  SELECT Sum(( B.price_per_l * ( 1 / B.km_per_l * A.km_of_journey ) ) + ( ( 
                      Datediff(hour, A.timein, 
                      A.timeout) * 500 ) * A.nr_of_trucks )) 
    FROM   Contract A 
           INNER JOIN Truck B 
                   ON A.plate_no = B.plate_no 
           INNER JOIN Client C 
                   ON A.contractid = C.contractid
```

Hope this helps.